# EF Add-Migration not detecting generics

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have the following class;

```
public class PricingRuleNumberRange
{
    public decimal? FromValue { get; private set; }
    public decimal? ToValue { get; private set; }

    protected PricingRuleNumberRange() {}

    public PricingRuleNumberRange(decimal? fromValue, decimal? toValue)
    {
        FromValue = fromValue;
        ToValue = toValue;
    }

    ...
}
```

And a model which uses said class;

```
public class PricingRule
{
    public PricingRuleNumberRange LVR { get; private set; }

    protected PricingRule() { }

    public PricingRule(...)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void UpdateDetails(PricingRuleNumberRange lvr)
    {
        LVR = lvr;
    }
}
```

I can add a new `PricingRuleNumberRange` property to `PricingRule` and call `Add-Migration`, it will detect and scaffold the change without issue. However, I now need to add another `PricingRuleNumberRange` property that is only an `int`, not a `decimal`. I thought that converting the `PricingRuleNumberRange` to a generic class would be acceptable but `Add-Migration` now drops the `LVR` property/columns.

This is the new code;

```
public class PricingRuleNumberRange<T> where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
    public T? FromValue { get; private set; }
    public T? ToValue { get; private set; }

    protected PricingRuleNumberRange() {}

    public PricingRuleNumberRange(T? fromValue, T? toValue)
    {
        FromValue = fromValue;
        ToValue = toValue;
    }

    ...
}

public class PricingRule
{
    public PricingRuleNumberRange<decimal> LVR { get; private set; }
    public PricingRuleNumberRange<int> NewCol { get; private set; }

    protected PricingRule() { }

    public PricingRule(...)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void UpdateDetails(PricingRuleNumberRange<decimal> lvr)
    {
        LVR = lvr;
    }
}
```

Since I am specifying `int`/`decimal` in the property declaration, I thought it would pick it up still, but obviously not. I suspect I might need to do something in the `DbContext.OnModelCreating()` method or maybe add some attributes to some properties to get it to work?

Comment: The reason is pretty clear. EF does know the generic type `class PricingRuleNumberRange`. So we need to explicitly tell the datatype

Comment: I am being explicit in the PricingRule class though. Surely reflection can figure that out. Otherwise, how do I explicitly tell it the datatype?